# How to play aes encrypted m3u8 with encrypted key in iOS in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, encryption, m3u8

because the server's resource is encrypted, so when I requested the server get the m3u8 link like this:

## EXTM3U

```
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://120.26.102.206:8888/av_key?key_id=test&v=0",IV=0x3fef2009c61b69d9ea1b47674881f012
#EXTINF:16.733333,
/KFu7198jRglxH1FWzQ6p63-l45g=/FqvN-_hHPQ-bLm3sLXqHgWWqSRLI/000000.ts
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://120.26.102.206:8888/av_key?key_id=test&v=0",IV=0xfcbad2ef8b68e2d76e49f59e5bf610f1
#EXTINF:1.233333,
/KFu7198jRglxH1FWzQ6p63-l45g=/FqvN-_hHPQ-bLm3sLXqHgWWqSRLI/000001.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I want get the URI when request the URL and append some new params like token so The server can return the key I want, but I can't
interception the request. What need I do?

Comment: Anyluck? I am also messed in same issue. Currently looking for the help from here. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/sc1791/Listings/AVARLDelegateDemo_APLViewController_m.html.